# Doubt on multiple choice question on nested series question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I have got this multiple choice question
If

$y= x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \dots \infty}}}$

then y(2) =

options are

1. $4$ only
2. $1$ only
3. Undefined
4. $4$ or $1$.

**My efforts**

at $x = 2$

$y = 2 + \sqrt y$ .......(equation A)

$(y - 2)^2 = y$

$y^2  - 5y  + 4 = 0$

hence $y = 4, 1$

But from equation 2, value of $y $ will always be greater than $1$ hence option (1) will be the correct answer. Am i right? While the text book ans says that option $(4)$ is correct. Kindly clear my doubt. I would very grateful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbook is overlooking some considerations that you hinted towards.

Yes, in one limited sense, $4$ or $1$ are possible candidate values. However, if it was both, that would mean $4 = y(2) = 1$, which is obviously nonsense. *(I guess one could argue that "or" means only one of those need be true, but one can make the counterargument that the "best" answer would narrow it down to one, singular, correct value.)*

You have found one way of invalidating $1$ as a value; I'd like to point out another, a bit more formal and general in nature.

We know that we can narrow things down more because we are really looking at the sequence $a_n$ defined by
$$
a_1 = x \qquad a_n = x+\sqrt{a_n}
$$
and note that
$$
y(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n
$$
Limits are unique: a function or sequence cannot have multiple limits.

One can easily approximate the limit just by calculating $a_n$ for large $n$. For instance, taking the expression which has $17$ twos in it, [Wolfram](https://bit.ly/3OwVR69) tells us that
$$
a_{17} \approx 3.9999999994255\ldots \text{ if } x = 2
$$
a fairly convincing hint that $y(2) = 4$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The value $1$ comes from consistently taking the negative value of the square root. By squaring the equation to solve it you lose the distinction between the positive and negative square root and get a quadratic which has both solutions.

You distinguish between them by checking which of the the solutions solves the original equation, as you have done, and only $4$ works.

The text book is simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much